# Redirect aspx file to same page for all parameters

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

What is the simplest, easiest way to send all these requests to a single, new page?  Call it www.mydomain.com/page.html.  Thanks in advance.

Using asp.net / web.config / url rewrite

I tried this.. but it is not working.

```
<rule name="nav rule" >
  <match url="^Nav\.aspx\/Page$" />
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/featured-listings.html" />
</rule>
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FDefault.aspx%2FPageID%3D104742
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D1968245%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2125546%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2125559%26%3D%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2125562%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2125563%26%3D%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2133142%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2148897%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2164928%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2167997%26%3D%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPrint%3D1%26PropertyID%3D2205618%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPropertyID%3D2015534%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPropertyID%3D2158616%26%3D,,%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPropertyID%3D2164928%26%3D,,,,,%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPropertyID%3D2176853%26%3D,,%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPropertyID%3D2205618%26%3D%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPropertyID%3D2210074%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2FListNow%2FProperty.aspx%3FPropertyID%3D2212548%26%3D%26
http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=/ListNow/Default.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [Url Rewriting library](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html) to reduce a lot of code.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to use a wildcard in <location path="nav.aspx">